# cloudinary crop with node.js doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I uploaded some image to cloudinary - tried to manipulate (crop) the image but get the same image url (not cropped) - bug in cloudinary npm or I miss something?

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
....
var sourceUrl = cloudinaryImageDetails.url;
var croppedUrl = cloudinary.url(sourceUrl, {
                                               width:30,
                                               height: 30,
                                               crop:'fill'
                                             })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cloudinary.url works when supplied with the `public_id` of the uploaded image as first argument (instead of full image's URL).

For example,

```
cloudinary.url (`public_id`, { width:30, height: 30, crop:'fill' })
```

outputs -

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/image/upload/c_fill,h_30,w_30/public_id
```